# Creating a stack bar chart using XML data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am doing an online tutorial (https://www.linkedin.com/learning/d3-js-essential-training-for-data-scientists/prepare-stack-data-using-map) trying to **create a stacked bar chart using xml data.**

Here is my data that I am loading in: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AhmadMobin/D3-Learning/main/data2.xml

Here is my code:

```
d3.xml ("data2.xml").then(function (data){

    var parseDate= d3.timeParse("%Y");

    //SETP 1: Setting up chart area variables
    var height= 200;
    var width= 500;
    var margin= {left: 50, right: 50, top:40, bottom: 0};

console.log(data);

xml=[].map.call(data.querySelectorAll("dat"), function(d){

    return {
        date: parseDate(d.getAttribute("id")),
        top: +d.querySelector("top").textContent ,
        middle: +d.querySelector("middle").textContent ,
        bottom: +d.querySelector("bottom").textContent
    };
})
console.log(xml);

    //STEP 2: Define scales
    var minDate = d3.min(data,function(d){ return d.date; });
    var maxDate = d3.max(data,function(d){ return d.date; });
    var x= d3.scaleTime()
             .domain([minDate,maxDate])
             .range([0,width]);
    var y= d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d){return d.top+d.middle+d.bottom;})])
              .range([height, 0]); 
 
    
     var categories= ['top', 'middle', 'bottom'];         

     //Declaring stack generator
     var stack= d3.stack().keys(categories); 

     //Declaring area generator
     var area= d3.area()
                 .x(function(d){return d;})
                 .y0(function(d){return d;})
                 .y1(function(d){return d;});

    //STEP 2: Setting up chart area
    var svg= d3.select("body").append("svg")
               .attr("width", "100%")
               .attr("height", "100%");

    var chartGroup= svg.append("g") 
                        .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")"); 
                        
    //Running Stack Generator
    var stacked=stack(xml);   
    console.log(stacked);                 


});
```

**It is at step 2 where I define the scales where I get thrown this error:**

d3.v6.min.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t is not iterable at Object.Y [as min] (d3.v6.min.js:2) at stack.js:28

Not sure what I am doing wrong or what the error even means.

Comment: Think you want to get minDate & maxDate from `xml` array. Confusing calling it `xml` when it's an array of plain objects

Answer (score 0):

As per [@charlieftli's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143854/creating-a-stack-bar-chart-using-xml-data/67144421#comment118682720_67143854) this works! **Please upvote his comment!**

```
    var minDate = d3.min(xml,function(d){ return d.date; });
    var maxDate = d3.max(xml,function(d){ return d.date; });
    var x= d3.scaleTime()
             .domain([minDate,maxDate])
             .range([0,width]);
    var y= d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain([0,d3.max(xml, function(d){return d.top+d.middle+d.bottom;})])
              .range([height, 0]);
```